# Transpose data.frame in r

Tags: r

Sorry for duplicate question. But I still can't find the answer.
I have a data.frame:

```
   Time                 EventName
1  2015-09-10 14:17:21   logged_in
2  2015-09-10 14:17:37 deauthorize
3  2015-09-10 14:17:42   logged_in
4  2015-09-10 14:17:42 deauthorize
5  2015-09-10 14:18:24   logged_in
6  2015-09-10 14:21:06 deauthorize
7  2015-09-10 14:21:13   logged_in
8  2015-09-10 14:21:52 deauthorize
9  2015-09-10 14:51:11   logged_in
10  2015-09-10 15:11:39 deauthorize
11  2015-09-10 15:30:43   logged_in
12  2015-09-10 15:30:44 deauthorize
```

and i want to transpose it to :

```
                                 1                   2                   3
logged_in      2015-09-10 14:17:21 2015-09-10 14:17:42 2015-09-10 14:18:24 
deauthorize    2015-09-10 14:17:37 2015-09-10 14:17:42 2015-09-10 14:21:06
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3):

This could be another option

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(setDT(dat)[, toString(Time), by=EventName], 'V1', ',')
```

Comment: Thx, but i need it for calculate times between  logged_in and deathorized. And in this case don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: @Smasell what do you exactly mean by "calculate time" can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `aggregate()` function.

Say your name of the data frame is 'dat', then

```
aggregate(dat$Time, list(dat$EventName),cbind)
```

or

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ EventName, dat, I))
```

should do the work.

**data**

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="   Time                 EventName
1  '2015-09-10 14:17:21'   logged_in
2  '2015-09-10 14:17:37' deauthorize
3  '2015-09-10 14:17:42'   logged_in
4  '2015-09-10 14:17:42' deauthorize
5  '2015-09-10 14:18:24'   logged_in
6  '2015-09-10 14:21:06' deauthorize
7  '2015-09-10 14:21:13'   logged_in
8  '2015-09-10 14:21:52' deauthorize
9  '2015-09-10 14:51:11'   logged_in
10  '2015-09-10 15:11:39' deauthorize
11  '2015-09-10 15:30:43'   logged_in
12  '2015-09-10 15:30:44' deauthorize", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: hope it okay to edit (if not please roll back) ... not sure the first code gives the right output (perhaps `aggregate(dat$Time, list(dat$EventName), function(x) cbind(as.character(x))) ` but then you still have a structure of a matrix embedded in a dataframe - hence the addition of the do.call)

Comment: `?"I"` ... its the identity/asis function, used here will return the object. (i must say i wouldn't actually use aggregate for this / i would use `reshape`

Comment: thanks @user20650 for the edit. i didnt think of  the matrix structure